# Custom PopUp modal component not showing when clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, state, react-props

I am trying to show a custom PopUp component on the screen when a user clicks on the Info icon but nothing is rendering in the UI when clicked.

I'm not exactly certain where I'm going wrong if anyone could provide some guidance?

Here is my Card component with PopUp inside the return:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import PopUp from './PopUp';

const WelcomeCard = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const togglePop = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <Card className='m-3 p-2 welcome-card rounded'>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Text className='mt-4'>{props.text}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
        <button>{props.button}</button>
        {show && <PopUp toggle={togglePop} />}
        <InfoIcon className='info-icon' onClick={togglePop} />
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default WelcomeCard;
```

And my actual PopUp component itself:

```
import React from 'react';

const PopUp = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.toggle();
  };

  return (
    <div className='modal'>
      <div className='modal_content'>
        <span className='close' onClick={handleClick}>
          &times;
        </span>
        <form>
          <h3>Register!</h3>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type='text' name='name' />
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type='submit' />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PopUp;
```

Would really appreciate some help on this one to understand it better, thanks in advance!

Comment: A bootstrap `.modal` is hidden by default; you're rendering the HTML if `show` is true, but not also turning it visible. Also, you're mixing react-bootstrap with the non-react version; just use the react version instead: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live

Comment: Here's the proper way: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-allen-on5s2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much, that's amazing and exactly the help I needed!